# Sync to BigQuery in Java "Repeated record added outside of an array"

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I am trying to insert a row to BigQuery using java.
The entity I was inserting has a field which is double nested.

Generating the entity suitable for BigQuery:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String barcodeDetailsJSON = order.getBarcodeDetailsJSON();
List<StateForBQ> stateForBQList = new ArrayList<StateForBQ>();
for (State state : order.getStates()) {
  StateForBQ stateForBQ = new StateForBQ(state);
  stateForBQ.setSetOn(new Date(stateForBQ.getSetOn().getTime()/1000));
  stateForBQList.add(stateForBQ);
}
  List<BarcodeDetailForBQ> barcodeDetailForBQList = getBarcodeDetailsFromBarcodeDetailsJSON(barcodeDetailsJSON, order.getIsGrouped());
```

Without the following, state is getting set as null. (State is nested entity)

```
  List<Map<String, Object>> stateMap = 
      mapper.convertValue(stateForBQList, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {});
```

Without the following, barcodeDetails is getting set as null. (BarcodeDetails is double nested entity)

```
  List<Map<String, Object>> barcodeMapList = 
      mapper.convertValue(barcodeDetailForBQList, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {});
```

Without the follwing, productPriceDetails, productDetails, cgst, sgst are getting set as null

```
  for (Map<String, Object> barcodeMap : barcodeMapList) {
      barcodeMap.put("productPriceDetails", mapper.convertValue(barcodeMap.get("productPriceDetails"), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {}));
      barcodeMap.put("productDetails", mapper.convertValue(barcodeMap.get("productDetails"), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {}));
      barcodeMap.put("cgst", mapper.convertValue(barcodeMap.get("cgst"), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {}));
      barcodeMap.put("sgst", mapper.convertValue(barcodeMap.get("sgst"), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {}));
}
```

Preparing the rowcontent

```
  Map<String, Object> rowContent = new HashMap<>();
  rowContent.put("orderId", order.getOrderId());
  rowContent.put("customerId", order.getCustomerId());
  rowContent.put("barcodeDetails", barcodeMapList);
  rowContent.put("states", stateMap);
```

Inserting to BigQuery

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
String datasetName = "Latest_Data";
String tableName= "ORDER_TEMP";
  // [START bigquery_table_insert_rows]
  TableId tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, tableName);
  // Values of the row to insert

String barcodeDetailsJSON = order.getBarcodeDetailsJSON();
  List<BarcodeDetailForBQ> barcodeDetailForBQList = new OrderForBQ().getBarcodeDetailsFromBarcodeDetailsJSON(barcodeDetailsJSON, order.getIsGrouped());

  String recordsContentString = gson.toJson(rowContent);

  InsertAllResponse response =
      bigquery.insertAll(
          InsertAllRequest.newBuilder(tableId)
              .addRow(""+orderId, rowContent)
              // More rows can be added in the same RPC by invoking .addRow() on the builder
              .build());

  if (response.hasErrors()) {
    // If any of the insertions failed, this lets you inspect the errors
    for (Entry<Long, List<BigQueryError>> entry : response.getInsertErrors().entrySet()) {
      // inspect row error
    }
  }
```

Following is the response I am getting.

```
{
  insertErrors: {
    0: [
      {
        reason: "invalid",
        location: "",
        message: "Repeated record added outside of an array."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```